# SpringBoot bean registration via GenericApplicationContext does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, spring-bean

I have a simple bean registration here during runtime that doesn't work:

```
@GetMapping("/hi")
public void hi()
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    genericApplicationContext.registerBean("mybean", MyClass.class, myClass);
}

@GetMapping("/bye")
public Integer bye()
{
    MyClass myClass = (MyClass) genericApplicationContext.getBean("mybean");
    return myClass.hi;
}
```

Calling method `hi()` everything goes normally, however when I call `bye()` method I get this exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mybean': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)] with root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mybean': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

What's going on here?

Comment: _Why_ are you trying to do this? It's not at all customary, and there's probably a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is this: I'm creating a spring library that is supposed to create a bean based on consumer's input: e.g. database credentials.

Comment: So it should probably be a Spring Boot starter and use auto-configuration and `@ConfigurationProperties`. I suggest examining the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` class in Spring Boot for an example.

Comment: How should the consumer then access the bean created by the library?

Comment: Using autowiring, the same as every other Spring bean. Ideally, by expressing it as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Would you mind explaining that a bit further, please?

What I need would be: library consumer passes some parameters to library, library creates 1 bean that consumer will use and creates 2 additional beans for itself that it will use. How should consumer go about using that bean, since it cannot see those beans?

Comment: What do you mean "cannot see those beans"? It doesn't sound like you've built a Spring Boot application, which would give you some sense of how these things work.